# How to sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, data-structures

How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a specific key's value? Given:

```py
[{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}]
```

When sorted by `name`, it should become:

```py
[{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}]
```

Comment: Reading the answer and looking on [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Can I sort on multiple value in the same process (for example we have `[{'name':'Bart', 'age':10, 'note':3},{'name':'Homer','age':10,'note':2},{'name':'Vasile','age':20,'note':3}]`

And to use:
`from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(old_list, key=itemgetter(-'note','name')`

EDIT: Tested, and it is working but I don't know how to make note DESC and name ASC.

Answer (score 3650, accepted):

The [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) function takes a `key=` parameter

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda d: d['name'])
```

Alternatively, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of defining the function yourself

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=itemgetter('name'))
```

For completeness, add `reverse=True` to sort in descending order

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=itemgetter('name'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Using key is not only cleaner but more effecient too.

Comment: The fastest way would be to add a newlist.reverse() statement. Otherwise you can define a comparison like cmp=lambda x,y: - cmp(x['name'],y['name']).

Comment: if the sort value is a number you could say:

lambda k: (k['age'] * -1)

to get a reverse sort

Comment: This also applies to a list of tuples, if you use `itemgetter(i)` where `i` is the index of the tuple element to sort on.

Comment: `itemgetter` accepts more than one argument: `itemgetter(1,2,3)` is a function that return a tuple like `obj[1], obj[2], obj[3]`, so you can use it to do complex sorts.

Comment: in case of unicode strings `import locale / locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "") / newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: locale.strxfrm(k['name']))` works  inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-unicode-strings-alphabetically-in-python

Comment: what if we don't know the value of key?

Comment: operator.itemgetter worked for me, the first option didn't work or maybe I didn't fill in the right info... lambda? d: ?

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Bakuriu is there any way to do complex sorts with both ascending and descending order? e.g. `key=itemgetter("speed", "color", "cost"), reverse=(True, False, True)`

Comment: @ciurlaro Not that I know of. In order to make that work you'd first have to `map` the values in a way that make the fields you want sort in the opposite direction, then use a plain sort by those fields and at the end "un-wrap" the values. Obviously instead of using `itemgetter` you could use a custom function and do whatever you want there.

Comment: @ciurlaro Note that in python sorting is stable, so say you want to achieve the equivalent of `key=itemgetter('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), reverse=(True, True, False, True, True)` you could do that by sorting 3 times: first on `D, E` with `reverse=True`, then on `C` with `reverse=False` and finally on `A,B` with `reverse=True`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842689/3004162 that worked to achieve what I wanted. Still far from a beauty of a builtin function unfortunately, but that's the best I found

Comment: I have a list of dict_keys containing months which are unfortunately unordered. How should I order them from january...to...december? thanks

Comment: @ciurlaro you might want to forget `operator.itemgetter` in that case and write out the accesses the "old-fashioned" way, negating the "color". `key=lambda x: (x["speed"], -x["color"], x["cost"])`

Answer (score 240):

```
import operator
```

To sort the list of dictionaries by key='name':

```
list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

To sort the list of dictionaries by key='age':

```
list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('age'))
```

Comment: Anyway to combine name and age ? (like in SQL ORDER BY name,age ?)

Comment: @monojohnny: yes, just have the key return a tuple, `key=lambda k: (k['name'], k['age'])`. (or `key=itemgetter('name', 'age')`). tuple's `cmp` will compare each element in turn. it's bloody brilliant.

Comment: In the documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) the optional `key` argument for `list.sort()` is not described. Any idea where to find that?

Comment: @TTT: See the [library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for `list` and friends.

Answer (score 121):

```
my_list = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]

my_list.sort(lambda x,y : cmp(x['name'], y['name']))
```

`my_list` will now be what you want.

Or better:

Since Python 2.4, there's a `key` argument is both more efficient and neater:

```
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

...the lambda is, IMO, easier to understand than `operator.itemgetter`, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: what could be done if the key is unknown and keeps changing?I mean list of dicts with just one key and value but the key and value could not be defined as they keep changing.

Comment: I'd need more of an example to look at.  Try submitting a possible solution on the codereview stackexchange and asking if there's a better way.

Comment: @Sam if you want to sort by the value of the single key in the dict, even if you don't know the key, you can do `key=lambda k: list(k.values())[0]`

Answer (score 75):

If you want to sort the list by multiple keys, you can do the following:

```
my_list = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Milhouse', 'age':10}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10} ]
sortedlist = sorted(my_list , key=lambda elem: "%02d %s" % (elem['age'], elem['name']))
```

It is rather hackish, since it relies on converting the values into a single string representation for comparison, but it works as expected for numbers including negative ones (although you will need to format your string appropriately with zero paddings if you are using numbers).

Comment: sorted using timsort which is stable, you can call sorted several times to have a sort on several criteria

Comment: njzk2's comment wasn't immediately clear to me so I found the following.  You can just sort twice as njzk2 suggests, or pass multiple arguments to operator.itemgetter in the top answer.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria

Comment: No need to convert to string. Just return a tuple as the key.

Comment: Sorting multiple times is the easiest generic solution without hacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29849371/1805397

Answer (score 54):

```
a = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, ...]

# This changes the list a
a.sort(key=lambda k : k['name'])

# This returns a new list (a is not modified)
sorted(a, key=lambda k : k['name'])
```

Answer (score 42):

```
import operator
a_list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

'key' is used to sort by an arbitrary value and 'itemgetter' sets that value to each item's 'name' attribute.

Answer (score 32):

I guess you've meant:

```
[{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]
```

This would be sorted like this:

```
sorted(l,cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x['name'],y['name']))
```

Answer (score 29):

You could use a custom comparison function, or you could pass in a function that calculates a custom sort key. That's usually more efficient as the key is only calculated once per item, while the comparison function would be called many more times.

You could do it this way:

```
def mykey(adict): return adict['name']
x = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age':10}]
sorted(x, key=mykey)
```

But the standard library contains a generic routine for getting items of arbitrary objects: `itemgetter`. So try this instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter
x = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age':10}]
sorted(x, key=itemgetter('name'))
```

Answer (score 28):

Sometime we need to use `lower()` for case-insensitive sorting. For example,

```
lists = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39},
  {'name':'Bart', 'age':10},
  {'name':'abby', 'age':9}]

lists = sorted(lists, key=lambda k: k['name'])
print(lists)
# Bart, Homer, abby
# [{'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, {'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'abby', 'age':9}]

lists = sorted(lists, key=lambda k: k['name'].lower())
print(lists)
# abby, Bart, Homer
# [ {'name':'abby', 'age':9}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, {'name':'Homer', 'age':39}]
```

Comment: *Why* do we need to use lower() in this case?

Comment: The most likely reason to need to use `lower()` here would be to provide case-insensitive alphabetical sorting.  This sample dataset has a lower-case a with _abby_ and an upper-case B with _Bart_, so the examples show the results without, and then with, case-insensitive sort via `.lower()`.

Answer (score 27):

Using the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) from Perl,

```
py = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]
```

do

```
sort_on = "name"
decorated = [(dict_[sort_on], dict_) for dict_ in py]
decorated.sort()
result = [dict_ for (key, dict_) in decorated]
```

gives

```
>>> result
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Bart'}, {'age': 39, 'name': 'Homer'}]
```

More on the Perl Schwartzian transform:

> In computer science, the Schwartzian transform is a Perl programming
> idiom used to improve the efficiency of sorting a list of items. This
> idiom is appropriate for comparison-based sorting when the ordering is
> actually based on the ordering of a certain property (the key) of the
> elements, where computing that property is an intensive operation that
> should be performed a minimal number of times. The Schwartzian
> Transform is notable in that it does not use named temporary arrays.

Comment: Python has supported the `key=` for `.sort` since 2.4, that is year 2004, it does the Schwartzian transform within the sorting code, in C; thus this method is useful only on Pythons 2.0-2.3. all of which are more than 12 years old.

Answer (score 24):

You have to implement your own comparison function that will compare the dictionaries by values of name keys. See [Sorting Mini-HOW TO from PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: This relies too much on the link. Can you provide a more complete answer?

Comment: Proper anwers are already provided by other contributors as well. Feel free to either keep the link, or delete the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Using the [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) package is another method, though its runtime at large scale is much slower than the more traditional methods proposed by others:

```
import pandas as pd

listOfDicts = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfDicts)
df = df.sort_values('name')
sorted_listOfDicts = df.T.to_dict().values()
```

Here are some benchmark values for a tiny list and a large (100k+) list of dicts:

```
setup_large = "listOfDicts = [];\
[listOfDicts.extend(({'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10})) for _ in range(50000)];\
from operator import itemgetter;import pandas as pd;\
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfDicts);"

setup_small = "listOfDicts = [];\
listOfDicts.extend(({'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}));\
from operator import itemgetter;import pandas as pd;\
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfDicts);"

method1 = "newlist = sorted(listOfDicts, key=lambda k: k['name'])"
method2 = "newlist = sorted(listOfDicts, key=itemgetter('name')) "
method3 = "df = df.sort_values('name');\
sorted_listOfDicts = df.T.to_dict().values()"

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup_small)
print('Small Method LC: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup_small)
print('Small Method LC2: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method3, setup_small)
print('Small Method Pandas: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))

t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup_large)
print('Large Method LC: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup_large)
print('Large Method LC2: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method3, setup_large)
print('Large Method Pandas: ' + str(t.timeit(1)))

#Small Method LC: 0.000163078308105
#Small Method LC2: 0.000134944915771
#Small Method Pandas: 0.0712950229645
#Large Method LC: 0.0321750640869
#Large Method LC2: 0.0206089019775
#Large Method Pandas: 5.81405615807
```

Comment: I ran your code and found a mistake in the the timeit.Timer args for Large Method Pandas: you specify "setup_small" where it should be "setup_large".  Changing that arg caused the program to run without finishing, and I stopped it after more than 5 minutes.  When I ran it with "timeit(1)", the Large Method Pandas finished in 7.3 sec, much worse than LC or LC2.

Comment: You're quite right, that was quite an oversight on my part. I no longer recommend it for large cases! I have edited the answer to simply allow it as a possibility, the use case is still up for debate.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the alternative general solution - it sorts elements of a dict by keys and values.

The advantage of it - no need to specify keys, and it would still work if some keys are missing in some of dictionaries.

```
def sort_key_func(item):
    """ Helper function used to sort list of dicts

    :param item: dict
    :return: sorted list of tuples (k, v)
    """
    pairs = []
    for k, v in item.items():
        pairs.append((k, v))
    return sorted(pairs)
sorted(A, key=sort_key_func)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"sorts elements of a dict by keys and values"*? In what way is it sorting? Where do the values come in?

Answer (score 16):

I have been a big fan of a filter with lambda. However, it is not best option if you consider time complexity.

#### First option

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key= lambda x: x['name'])
# Returns list of values
```

#### Second option

```
list_to_sort.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
# Edits the list, and does not return a new list
```

#### Fast comparison of execution times

```bash
# First option
python3.6 -m timeit -s "list_to_sort = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, {'name':'Faaa', 'age':57}, {'name':'Errr', 'age':20}]" -s "sorted_l=[]" "sorted_l = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda e: e['name'])"
```

> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.736 µsec per loop

```bash
# Second option
python3.6 -m timeit -s "list_to_sort = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, {'name':'Faaa', 'age':57}, {'name':'Errr', 'age':20}]" -s "sorted_l=[]" -s "import operator" "list_to_sort.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))"
```

> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.438 µsec per loop

Answer (score 15):

Let's say I have a dictionary `D` with the elements below. To sort, just use the key argument in `sorted` to pass a custom function as below:

```
D = {'eggs': 3, 'ham': 1, 'spam': 2}
def get_count(tuple):
    return tuple[1]

sorted(D.items(), key = get_count, reverse=True)
# Or
sorted(D.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # Avoiding get_count function call
```

Check [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions) out.

Answer (score 13):

If you do not need the original `list` of `dictionaries`, you could modify it in-place with `sort()` method using a custom key function.

Key function:

```
def get_name(d):
    """ Return the value of a key in a dictionary. """

    return d["name"]
```

The `list` to be sorted:

```
data_one = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}]
```

Sorting it in-place:

```
data_one.sort(key=get_name)
```

If you need the original `list`, call the `sorted()` function passing it the `list` and the key function, then assign the returned sorted `list` to a new variable:

```
data_two = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}]
new_data = sorted(data_two, key=get_name)
```

Printing `data_one` and `new_data`.

```
>>> print(data_one)
[{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}]
>>> print(new_data)
[{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}]
```

Answer (score 11):

If performance is a concern, I would use `operator.itemgetter` instead of `lambda` as built-in functions perform faster than hand-crafted functions. The `itemgetter` function seems to perform approximately 20% faster than `lambda` based on my testing.

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed:

> Likewise, the builtin functions run faster than hand-built equivalents. For example, map(operator.add, v1, v2) is faster than map(lambda x,y: x+y, v1, v2).

Here is a comparison of sorting speed using `lambda` vs `itemgetter`.

```
import random
import operator

# Create a list of 100 dicts with random 8-letter names and random ages from 0 to 100.
l = [{'name': ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=8)), 'age': random.randint(0, 100)} for i in range(100)]

# Test the performance with a lambda function sorting on name
%timeit sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['name'])
13 µs ± 388 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Test the performance with itemgetter sorting on name
%timeit sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
10.7 µs ± 38.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Check that each technique produces the same sort order
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['name']) == sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
True
```

Both techniques sort the list in the same order (verified by execution of the final statement in the code block), but the first one is a little faster.

Answer (score 5):

It might be better to use `dict.get()` to fetch the values to sort by in the sorting key. One way it's better than `dict[]` is that a default value may be used to if a key is missing in some dictionary in the list.

For example, if a list of dicts were sorted by `'age'` but `'age'` was missing in some dict, that dict can either be pushed to the back of the sorted list (or to the front) by simply passing `inf` as a default value to `dict.get()`.

```py
lst = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Lisa'}]

sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d['age'])                     # KeyError: 'age'
sorted(lst, key=itemgetter('age'))                      # KeyError: 'age'

# push dicts with missing keys to the back
sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d.get('age', float('inf')))   # OK
# push dicts with missing keys to the front
sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d.get('age', -float('inf')))  # OK

# if the value to be sorted by is a string
# '~' because it has the highest printable ASCII value
sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d.get('name', '~'))           # OK
```

Answer (score 5):

You can sort a list of dictionaries with a key as shown below:

```py
person_list = [
  {'name':'Bob','age':18}, {'name':'Kai','age':36}, {'name':'Ada','age':24} 
]
                                       # Key ↓
print(sorted(person_list, key=lambda x: x['name']))
```

Output:

```
[
  {'name':'Ada','age':24}, {'name':'Bob','age':18}, {'name':'Kai','age':36}
]
```

In addition, you can sort a list of dictionaries with a key and a list of values as shown below:

```py
person_list = [
  {'name':'Bob','age':18}, {'name':'Kai','age':36}, {'name':'Ada','age':24} 
]

name_list = ['Kai', 'Ada', 'Bob'] # Here
                                      # ↓ Here ↓       # Key ↓
print(sorted(person_list, key=lambda x: name_list.index(x['name'])))
```

Output:

```
[
  {'name':'Kai', 'age':36}, {'name':'Ada', 'age':24}, {'name':'Bob','age':18}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @Claudiu to @monojohnny in comment section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465/7658051),
 given:

```
list_to_be_sorted = [
                      {'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, 
                      {'name':'Milhouse', 'age':10}, 
                      {'name':'Bart', 'age':10} 
                    ]
```

to sort the list of dictionaries by key `'age'`, `'name'`

(like in SQL statement `ORDER BY age, name`), you can use:

```
newlist = sorted( list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: (k['age'], k['name']) )
```

or, likewise

```
import operator
newlist = sorted( list_to_be_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter('age','name') )
```

`print(newlist)`

> [{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10},
>   {'name': 'Milhouse', 'age': 10},
> {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}]

Answer (score 1):

sorting by multiple columns, while in descending order on some of them:
the cmps array is global to the cmp function, containing field names and inv == -1 for desc 1 for asc

```
def cmpfun(a, b):
    for (name, inv) in cmps:
        res = cmp(a[name], b[name])
        if res != 0:
            return res * inv
    return 0

data = [
    dict(name='alice', age=10), 
    dict(name='baruch', age=9), 
    dict(name='alice', age=11),
]

all_cmps = [
    [('name', 1), ('age', -1)], 
    [('name', 1), ('age', 1)], 
    [('name', -1), ('age', 1)],]

print 'data:', data
for cmps in all_cmps: print 'sort:', cmps; print sorted(data, cmpfun)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
lst = [{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10}]
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['age']) # change this to sort by a different field
print(sorted_lst)
```